# Changing date format in a Node js project

Tags: node.js, date

I am creating a Node js project which connects to an API and returns a date in the format of 2021-02-28T22:46:01.000-0500  I would like to convert this date to a format of mm/dd/yyyy format.  Even better if its mm/dd/yyy hh:mm:ss

This is the current line of code.

```
this.createdDate = djItem.fields.created
```

What do I need to add to update the date format?

I am trying to create a function which can be used by two different lines of codes with dates.

```
this.createdDate = getDate(djItem.fields.created ? djItem.fields.created : 0);

getDate = function(date){
const dateAsNumber = date.parse(createdDate)
console.log(dateAsNumber)
const dateOptions = {
  month: "numeric",
  day: "numeric",
  year: "2-digit",
  hour: "numeric",
  minute: "numeric",
  second:"numeric",
  }
const newDateString = new Date(dateAsNumber).toLocaleDateString("us-en", dateOptions);
console.log(newDateString)
}
```

Current error is createdDate is not defined

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by first parsing the date time format (this will give you a timestamp as a bigint) and then by using the built in data function .toLocaleDateString() function with options that meet your needs.

```js
const dateAsNumber = Date.parse("2021-02-28T22:46:01.000-0500")
// it is now a number
console.log(dateAsNumber)
const dateOptions ={
  month: "numeric",
  day: "numeric",
  year: "2-digit",
  hour: "numeric",
  minute: "numeric",
  second:"numeric",
  }
const newDateString = new Date(dateAsNumber).toLocaleDateString("us-en", dateOptions);
console.log(newDateString)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I modified my original question with some code I created.  Getting an error on the variable as  createdDate is not defined

Comment: uhh, @JasonC have you initialized createdDate? with var createdDate or let createdDate?